# Check checkboxes in CheckboxGroupInput component while editing

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a form that display a Many-to-Many relationship between two entities Brand and Distribution.
I display the distributions through a CheckboxGroupInput component in a brand page. During the form edition (Edit component), I managed to pre-check distributions that have been checked previously during the creation (Create) (this is not specified in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#checkboxgroupinput)) but I can't check or uncheck any distributions.

Here's the edition form :

```
export class BrandEdit extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                isLoading: true
            }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        //Find all distributions
        restClient(GET_MANY, 'distribution', {
            sort: {field: 'name', order: 'ASC'}
        })
            .then(response => {
                return restClient(GET_ONE, 'brand', {
                    id: this.props.match.params.id
                }).then(brandResult => {
                    let distributionsIds = []
                    brandResult.data.distributions.forEach(distribution => {
                        distributionsIds.push(distribution.id)
                    })
                    this.setState({
                        distributions: response.data,
                        distribution_checked_ids: distributionsIds,
                        isLoading: false,
                    })
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, distributions, distribution_checked } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                {
                <Edit {...this.props}>
                    <SimpleForm>
                        <DisabledInput source="id"/>
                        <TextInput label="Nom" source="name"/>
                        <CheckboxGroupInput
                            source="distributions"
                            input={{
                                value: this.state.distribution_checked_ids,
                                onChange: (checkedDistributionIds) => {
                                    this.setState({ distribution_checked_ids: checkedDistributionIds });
                                }
                            }}
                            choices={distributions}
                            optionValue="id"
                            optionText="name"
                        />
                    </SimpleForm>
                </Edit>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to pass an array of Distribution id to the component and not and array of Distribution objects.

Here's the component :

```
<CheckboxGroupInput
    source="distributions"
    choices={distributions}
    optionValue="id"
    optionText="name"
/>
```

Data should look like :

```
{
 "id": 2115,
 "name": "Test",
 "distributions": [12, 13, 14]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `input` prop. Why would you handle form state by yourself? AOR uses redux-form to handle that.

Comment: AOR does this automatically if you follow the examples. The EDIT component fetches the data and send it to redux-form. redux-form makes sure all the inputs start with the right value.

Comment: Do you have any examples using CheckboxGroupInput component ?

Comment: I would suggest admin-on-rest-demo. It has source code and live demo!

Comment: I tried, but they don't use this component in the demo. Also, thanks for your answers

Comment: admin-on-rest repo has an example inside. The example project has this component in posts. download the repo and run `make run` to start the example.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. It's more understandable with the example!